# Matlab change a set of images to 2D grayscale but error occur

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to turn a set of images to 2D grayscale image in order to do Surf feature extraction. In the set, some of the images are already in 2D scale so when I tried to run a loop.
This error message happens:
**MAP must be a m x 3 array.**

Here is my code:

```
for ii=1:numImages
   
   img = readimage(imdsTrain,ii);
   RGB = rgb2gray(img)

   points = detectSURFFeatures(RGB);
   [surf1, valid_points] = extractFeatures(RGB, points);
   figure; imshow(RGB); hold on;
   plot(valid_points.selectStrongest(10),'showOrientation',true);
   title ('Ct-scan image with Surf feature')
 
end;
```

Is there any solution that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's rgb2gray will fail if you give it a grayscale image (an image with only one color channel).

If you are sure that your images are either m x n X 3 or m x n  x 1, you could check for the m x n  x 3 case before attempting to do the rgb2gray. If your image is already a grayscale image no conversion is needed or can be done via rgb2gray.

Something like this:

```
img = readimage(imdsTrain,ii);
[rows, columns, colors]  = size(img)
if colors > 1
   RGB = rgb2gray(img)
end
```

Now getting the error **MAP must be a m x 3 array** suggests that whatever you supplied rgb2gray got interpreted as a colormap. So I would check if all your images are indeed three dimensions, as you are assumimg.